# Issue in Inserting using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am trying to insert the data like this

```
function submitData() {
//Posting to ContactDB with JSON format
$.post("contactDB.php",
    JSON.stringify({ 
          name: $("#name").val(),
          email: $("#email").val(),
          phone: $("#phone").val(),
          message: $("#message").val() 
    }),
    function(usrava){
        // if data is inserted successfully than show insert success message in Result div
        if(usrava=='Data Inserted')
        {
            $("#result").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){ 
                $(this).html('Your message is successfully saved with us. We will get back to you soon.').fadeTo(900,1);
            });     
        }
        //else show the error 
        else
        {
            $("#result").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){ 
                $(this).html(usrava).fadeTo(900,1);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

### **ContactDB.php**

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "contactDB"); //Connection to the Database
    //If Error than die
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        //Echo for the response 
        echo "Data base connection NOT Successful. Please get the assistance from your Administrator.";
        //Should not go out if not connected
        exit();
    }
    //data received in json. decoded it to an array
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    //Create a insert Command using implode as the data is already in the array
    $insert = "INSERT INTO contact(Name,Email,Phone,Message) VALUES ('" .implode(",",$data)."')";
    $mysqli->query($insert);
    //Close the connection
    $mysqli->close();
    // Echo for the response
    echo "Data Inserted";
?>
```

The issue is I am getting error on `$mysqli->query($insert);` that `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near Rajesh, at line 1`

What should I do to make it run. I have tried everything but could not find any working solution. Please Help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: echo the $insert, I guess the syntax is not correct, Ok and check in your #result div what it is showing

Comment: $data is already an associative array, so using implode will make a different string then what you think, just print_r() the $data before executing the query, you'll see that it's not as per the SQL syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function implode will Join array elements with a string. Now your function is `implode(",",$data)` that will make the string something like this

```
NameData,EmailData,PhoneData,MessageData
```

Whereas you will be looking to make it like this

```
'NameData','EmailData','PhoneData','MessageData'
```

So to do that you need to make your implode function looks like this `implode("','",$data)` and the first and last `'`s is already coming in from the code you have written.

Comment: Wow a nice explanation to what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

There are some `string` values. You need to use the `'`s properly.

```
VALUES ('" .implode("','",$data)."')"
```

**Explanation**

The code you are using is generating something like - `VALUES ('name, email, phone, message')` which is wrong in syntax. They all are `string`s and need to wrapped in `'`s.

`('" . implode("', '", $data) . "')` - will wrap them up properly. It will generate - `VALUES ('name', 'email', 'phone', 'message')`

Comment: Could you please explain implode as I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$postdata =  implode("','", $data) ;

$insert = "INSERT INTO contact(Name,Email,Phone,Message) VALUES ('$postdata')";
```

Comment: You need to remove the `'`s around `$postdata`

Comment: Yes @b0s3 is correct. This will work without 's on `$postdata`